# Is it possible to install an optional script outside my main package with poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- I'm building a library, call it `mylib`, which hosts a module called `module.py`. The library should work independently so that, for example, the user may `import from mylib.mymodule` in a python console or Jupyter notebook.
- I'm building a CLI tool to interface with `mylib` and automatize some common tasks `mylib` is useful for. This script is called `myscript.py` and requires dependencies which are not needed by `mylib`.  At moment the script lives inside a folder `scripts` which is not included in `mylib`.
- I'd like to have the user install the project either with `poetry install --with myscript` or with `poetry install`
- If the user installed through `poetry install --with myscripts`, poetry should install the optional dependencies and let the user run the `myscript.py` with `poetry run myscript` or simply `myscript`.
- if the user installed through `poetry install`, poetry should *not* install the optional dependencies and `poetry run myscript` or simply `myscript` should fail.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior? If so, how? Do you know of any repo implementing a similiar workflow I could look at?

My project structure is the following:

```
/project_folder
|--/mylib
|----__init__.py
|----module.py
|--/scripts
|----myscript.py
|--/tests
|----__init__.py
|pyproject.toml
```

At moment my `pyproject.toml` has this extra line for optional dependecies:

```
[tool.poetry.group.myscript.dependencies]
schema = "^0.7.5"
```

I have read about `poetry.script` but it is unclear to me how to use it to achieve what I want. A trivial solution would be to create publish `mylib` and to create two separate project, one for `mylib` and one for `myscript.py`. But I'd avoid that for the moment, if possible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras